# Resteasy. Class def not found

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, resteasy

I'm building rest-client with *resteasy* and *wildfly*.
According to stacktrace probably I've got problems with dependecies.
Already done many tries regarding changes scopes, deleting or adding dependencies in **pom.xml** doesn't give any result except another stacktrace with something not found...
Here is my

> stacktrace

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/GenericType
    at groupId.Main.<init>(Main.java:33)
    at groupId.Main.main(Main.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

and

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
    Copyright 2013, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
    contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the
    distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
      <artifactId>restClient</artifactId>
      <groupId>groupId</groupId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>

   <artifactId>rest-client</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <name>restClient: WAR Module</name>

   <url>http://wildfly.org</url>
   <licenses>
      <license>
         <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
         <distribution>repo</distribution>
         <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
      </license>
   </licenses>

   <dependencies>

      <!-- Dependency on the EJB module so we can use it's services if needed -->

       <!--&lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs &ndash;&gt;-->

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
         <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
           <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>

           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
           <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
           <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxb-provider -->
       <!--<dependency>-->
       <!--<groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>-->
       <!--<artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>-->
       <!--<version>3.1.2.Final</version>-->
       <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
       <!--</dependency>-->

       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/ejb-api -->



       <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
           <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
           <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/ejb-api -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
           <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
           <version>3.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in JBoss WildFly -->
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>

           <version>1.0.0.Final</version>

       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
           <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                   <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
       <!--<dependency>-->
       <!--<groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>-->
       <!--<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>-->
       <!--<version>42.1.0</version>-->
       <!--</dependency>-->

       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
           <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
       </dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
           <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
           <version>2.5</version>
       </dependency>

   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
               <!-- Java EE 7 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the stacktrace, you're running a main method in IntelliJ.

All your RESTEasy dependencies are marked as 'provided'. This means the appliation expects the runtime container (e.g. an application server) to provide them. IntelliJ will not provide these dependencies at runtime itself and therefore you're getting the ClassNotFoundException error.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

> **provided**
>
> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK
> or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when
> building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would
> set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to
> scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This
> scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is
> not transitive.

To test the application in IntelliJ, simply remove the provided scopes.